# How to create a case-sensitive keybinding in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, elisp, key-bindings, case-sensitive

According to the [Emacs' manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Modifier-Keys.html), modifier keys are case-insensitive due to "historical reasons".

Can I change this behaviour?

My goal is making `M-a` and `M-A` to mean different things.

Thanks!

Comment: As far as I am aware, they are only treated as being case-insensitive if there is only one key definition.  If you create two -- i.e., one lower-case key definition and one upper-case key definition, then they are no longer treated as being case-insensitive.  Using the method you seek is very common.  E.g., `(global-set-key [?\s-m] 'minimize)` and `(global-set-key [?\s-M] 'maximize)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the manual,

> A <kbd>Control</kbd>-modified alphabetical character is always considered case-insensitive: Emacs always treats C-A as C-a, C-B as C-b, and so forth. The reason for this is historical.

So you couldn't define them like:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-a") 'xxx)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-A") 'yyy)
```

but `S-` can be used for <kbd>Shift</kbd>, so:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-a") 'xxx)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-S-a") 'yyy)  ;; C-A
```

is OK. And

> For all other modifiers, you can make the modified alphabetical characters case-sensitive when you customize Emacs. For instance, you could make M-a and M-A run different commands.

So you can define key-binding like this:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "M-a") 'xxx)
(global-set-key (kbd "M-A") 'yyy)
```

Comment: I do this quite often, actually.  It does mean calling out in the doc for my code, however, that `C-A` is aka `C-S-a` (or vice versa). Emacs itself always uses the latter notation, with the explicit Shift modifier.

Comment: It appears that in Emacs 29.1, `describe-key` translates it.

C-c l e (translated from C-c l E) runs the command lsp-execute-code-action,
which is an interactive byte-compiled Lisp function in ‘lsp-mode.el’.

The binding was set with 
    (define-key map "E" #'lsp-treemacs-errors-list)
    (define-key map "e" #'lsp-execute-code-action)
and
      (define-key scala-mode-map "\C-cl" map)